# Updating SSL Certificate on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I needed to update SSL Certificate for my site as it was expiring soon. I have updated it with heroku toolbelt with command

```
heroku certs:update
```

I can see that new cert is in use with command

```
heroku certs:info
```

Although, when I am checking which cert does site return via https it returns the old one, that will expire soon.

I have updated it yesterday

Comment: Do you have a `SSL Endpoint` add on as well as a SNI endpoint?